# Xaml Border input binding prevents animation on MouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a user control which acts similar to a button (see code below).

To get the user control animation I used EventTriggers to the mouse events (Enter/Leave, Down/Up).

After I've added the InputBinding to the MouseClick

```
<Border.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
</Border.InputBindings>
```

The animation of the MouseDown doesn't work anymore. Any suggestions how to add the ClickCommand and keeping the animation?

```
<UserControl x:Class="DauertestViewer.StationItemControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DauertestViewer"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="150">


    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ContentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#363637" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="150" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" >
                        <Border x:Name="border" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                CornerRadius="0"
                                Margin="10">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect
                                    x:Name="dropshadow"
                                    ShadowDepth="4"
                                    Direction="300"
                                    Color="#363637"
                                    Opacity="0.4"
                                    BlurRadius="4"/>
                            </Border.Effect>
                            <Border.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
                            </Border.InputBindings>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>                              
                                <Viewbox Grid.Row="0" Margin="5 8 5 5" >

                                </Viewbox>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
                                           Margin="0 0 0 2" 
                                           Text="{Binding StationName, FallbackValue=Dauertest}" 
                                           FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" 
                                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                           FontWeight="Regular"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"                                           
                                           TextAlignment="Center" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" SourceName="border">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard TargetName="dropshadow">
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BlurRadius" 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                                            From="4" 
                                            To="10" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave" SourceName="border">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard TargetName="dropshadow">
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BlurRadius" 
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                                            From="10" 
                                            To="4" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown" SourceName="border">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard TargetName="border">
                                        <ThicknessAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                                            From="10,10,10,10" To="10,10,15,15" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp" SourceName="border">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard TargetName="border">
                                        <ThicknessAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                                            From="10,10,15,15" To="10,10,10,10" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ContentStyle}"/>
```

The ViewModel:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace DauertestViewer
{
    public class StationItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public StationItem StationItem { get; set; }

        public string IconColor { get; set; }

        public string IconName { get; set; }

        public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

        public bool UpdateConnectionStatusInProgress { get; set; }

        public ConnectionStatus CurrentConnectionStatus { get; set; }

        public StationItemViewModel()
        {
            ClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() => PingIpAddress(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.230")));
        }

        private async void PingIpAddress(IPAddress StationIP)
        {
            await RunCommand(() => this.UpdateConnectionStatusInProgress, async () =>
            {
                Ping pingSender = new Ping();
                PingReply pingReply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(StationIP, 10000);

                if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    this.CurrentConnectionStatus = ConnectionStatus.Connected;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.CurrentConnectionStatus = ConnectionStatus.NotConnected;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the ClickCommand in the constructor everything works fine - it is something related to the RelayCommand itself....

Comment: The command is a "standard" RelayCommand. Executing something non-UI related (actually sending a Ping).

For me the animation is not working. If you press the left mouse button nothing happens. if you release it, the MouseUp animation is triggered.

Comment: It still works for me.